# SDL Tridion - Storage

Tags: 2011, content-delivery, configuration, storage-extensions

I want to know how Storage setting in the cd_storage_conf.xml file works. My application gets deployed on JBoss.

Can I modify this file so that Tridion loads\store from any path (outside JBoss, classpath, anywhere on local or remote)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The storage configuration indeed allows you to specify "storages", that may be database or file system based, then bind item types and subtypes to a specific storage.

For file-system based storages you can indeed specify *any* path you want, as long as the deployer has enough permissions to **write** to and **delete** from that location.

Once you set up your deployer to deploy to a given storage you have to make sure that the applications that read the content from there are configured in the same way, this time making sure they can **read** from that same location.

The examples in the cd_storage_conf comments should help you figure it out. Importantly, this file is only read at startup, so any changes you make require a restart of the JVM using it.

Comment: Can you please point to some example configuration?

Comment: @adi - Can you you give precise example as what actually your are looking for and what modification for what purpose you are trying to do?

Comment: For a sample storage with Session Preview and file system storage for pages & binaries (everything else in DB) see here: http://code.google.com/p/kickstart-tridion-environment/source/browse/CreateAnEnvironmentForMe/CreateAnEnvironmentForMe/ConfigSamples/preview-web/cd_storage_conf.xml