# Schema for cd_storage.xml and storage bundles

Tags: 2011, content-delivery, configuration

Related to [SDL Tridion - Storage](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/1400/sdl-tridion-storage/1401#1401):

Is there an XML Schema (XSD) definition (or other detailed documentation) for the cd_storage.xml and storage bundle xml files, including lists of valid nodes and values for node attributes?  The best I could find so far is [SDL Live Content](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/task_005JJFGGGD8858699HHFHJF), which is not exactly exhaustive.

If it exists already, could someone point me to the right place?  If not, can this be considered a polite request for it to be created?!

Many thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From your installation files, look in `..\Content Delivery\resources\schemas` - You will find `cd_storage_conf.xsd` and `cd_storage_dao_bundle.xsd`.

I generally add this (and all the other Tridion CD Schemas) as a Schema References in Visual Studio, it really helps when editing config files, and can help rapidly solve configuration issues.

**Update for Tridion 8.5:**

xsd's have moved into each microservice e.g.
..\SDL Web 8.5\Content Delivery\roles\discovery\standalone\config\schemas

Comment: Thanks (nod also to @siva-charan) for the tip on where to find the schema documents - it had completely slipped mind!  Now, as to documentation on valid / accepted values for nodes and attributes, any ideas?

Comment: The schema, sample configs and the docs (LiveContent) are your only source for attributes I am afraid. Is there something particular you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, but I'll post that as a separate question so that it can answered in its own right.

Answer (score 5):

The one you provided **[SDLLIVEContent](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/task_005JJFGGGD8858699HHFHJF)** link is the best one. The document explains all the possible nodes and attributes which needs to be taken care for Configuring content storage `cd_storage_conf.xml`

If you really wants to know the location of XSD, it is available

> Under Content Delivery Installation --> Resources --> Schemas --> cd_storage_conf.xsd

Answer (score 2):

You can refer the

> Content Delivery Installation --> Resources -->
>   configurations-->cd_storage_conf_sample.xml

there are good comments in the Sample files for storage & deployer config. 
e.g in deployer XSD there is no mention of Phase="post-transaction" (in my problem i was searching for the possible values in XSD but could not found), but sample file do have. so referring both can help you to document.

Comment: One correction Phase="post-transaction" is only related to Deployer config and not with Storage Config, I hope you mean to say that only

Comment: yes, i know that, check again, deployer is already mentioned in the start :)

Comment: The question is not asking for Deployer but for Storage only :)

Answer (score 2):

For configuration of storage layer in cd_storage_conf.xml you can collectively make use of the SDL Live Content links as stated in your question along with the sample storage config file where a descriptive comment has been added for almost all the nodes.

Related to Storage Bundle xml files, you may want to explore the Storage Extension related topics given [HERE](http://sdltridionworld.com/articles/sdltridion2011/tutorials/extending-content-delivery-storage-sdltridion-2011-3.aspx) and [HERE](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE&lang=en-US#url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql?c=t&pub=SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE&lang=en-US&action=search&query=Storage%2520Extension&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1372144231369&currentQuery=Storage%2520Extension&currentScope=&eventType=lcContent.loadDoctask_43B3B364CB804AEB990F0D772BF1D8D2&query=&scope=&filename=StoringExistingItemTypesDifferently.xml&docid=task_43B3B364CB804AEB990F0D772BF1D8D2&inner_id=&tid=&addHistory=true&resource=) (Requires Login).

In brief, Storage DAO Bundle xml file is generally used for extending the default functionality of Storage Layer of the Content Delivery module.

Typically, the content of a storage dao bundle file will look like as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StorageDAOBundles>
    <StorageDAOBundle type="<Which type of storage layer>">
          <StorageDAO typeMapping="<Which Action>"
                 class="Fully resolved custom storage layer extension class name" />
     </StorageDAOBundle>
</StorageDAOBundles>
```

For example:

1. For a Dynamic Component Presentation you want to invoke the Storage Extension at Publishing Action, the Storage DAO Bundle will looks as below:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <StorageDAOBundles>
       <StorageDAOBundle type="persistence">
           <StorageDAO typeMapping="PublishAction"
               class="com.tridion.storage.extension.custom.JPAPublishActionDAO" />
           </StorageDAOBundle>
   </StorageDAOBundles>
   ```
2. If you want to invoke Storage Extension while publishing a page, the Storage DAO Bundle will looks as below:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <StorageDAOBundles>
       <StorageDAOBundle type="filesystem">
           <StorageDAO typeMapping="Page"
               class="com.tridion.storage.extension.custom.FSPagePublishActionDAO" />
           </StorageDAOBundle>
   </StorageDAOBundles>
   ```

I hope it helps.